# How to query JSON with JS API to return JSON properties?

Tags: javascript, json, api

Apologies if this seems basic to some, but I'm new to JS/node.js/JSON and still finding my way. I've searched this forum for an hour but cannot find a specific solution.

I have a basic website setup running of a local Node.js server along with 2x JSON data files with information about 32x local suburbs.

An example of an API GET request URL on the site would be:

```
.../api/b?field=HECTARES
```

The structure of the JSON files are like:

[JSON Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nhB1.png)

In the JSON file there are 32x Features (suburbs), each with it's own list of Properties as shown above. What I am trying to do is use the API 'field' query to push all the HECTARES values each of the 32x Features into a single output variable. The code below is an example of how far I have got:

```
var fieldStats = [];
var fieldQ = req.query['field'];
for (i in suburbs.features) {
    x = suburbs.features[i].properties.HECTARES;
    fieldStats.push(x);
}
```

As you can see in the above "HECTARES" is hard-coded - I need to be able to pass the 'fieldQ' variable to this code but have no idea how to.

Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same syntax you are using just above:

```
suburbs.features[i].properties[fieldQ];
```

Comment: Thanks, works a charm - it's the little things in life. (Have spent half the day fighting with this!)